# Uniformly varied circular motion

Tags: graphics

How do I get a plot with the results of the angles, speeds and accelerations theta3 e theta4 for each input angle value theta2?
Where: R1 = 450, R2 = 125, R3 = 348 and R4 = 215.
Initial speed = 25 rad/s and circular acceleration = 40 rad/s^2
[image]

Comment: Usually I show some attempts, but at the moment I am without the software. Thanks to anyone who can help ...

Comment: Extraordinary. Could it be a graph with theta2 the x-axis and y-axis in theta3? Would be six charts: angles theta2 x theta3, angles theta2 x theta4, speeds theta2 x theta3, speeds theta2 x theta4, accelerations theta2 x theta3 and accelerations theta2 x theta4.

Comment: That is, for each degree theta2 how many degrees theta 3 moved ...

Comment: What happened to the previous answer? It was not exactly what I needed, but it is very useful ...

Comment: I believe the correct term to be no doubt is "plot" and not "graphic" ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thank Rahul for pointing out my blunder.

In the following I have changed R3 to be 360 to allow this linkage system to operate. I am not sure whether R3 is meant to be fixed or whether the specified angular speed and angular acceleration are for rotations around O1 and O2 and thus R3 would vary.

I post this in case it is helpful or motivating for the desired outcome. I plot the angles as per diagram v time.

Setup:

```
r1 = 450;
r2 = 125;
r3 = 360;
r4 = 215;
w = 25;
a = 40;
theta[t_] := w t + a t^2/2;
f1 = {0, 0};
f2 = {r1, 0};
p01 = {r2, 0};
p1[t_] := RotationMatrix[theta[t]].p01
p2[t_] := {x, y} /. 
  Solve[{Norm[{x, y} - f2] == r4, Norm[{x, y} - p1[t]] == r3}, {x, y}]
angle[u_] := With[{q = p2[u][[2]]}, ArcTan[#2/#1 & @@ (q - f2)]]
angle2[u_] := 
 With[{v = p2[u][[2]] - p1[t]}, ArcTan[#2/#1 & @@ (v - f2)]]
anim[t_] := 
 With[{pos1 = p1[t], pos2 = p2[t][[2]]}, 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Red, Circle[f1, r2], Circle[f2, r4], Dashing[{}], 
    Yellow, Thickness[0.01], Line[{f1, f2}], Line[{f1, pos1}], 
    Line[{f2, pos2}], Line[{pos1, pos2}], White, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[{f1, f2, pos1, pos2}], PointSize[0.025], Purple, 
    Point[{f1, f2, pos1, pos2}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-200, 700}, {-250, 250}}, Background -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> 250]]
```

The following gif was produced from this sequence of images:

```
tabu = With[{lp = 
     Plot[{Mod[theta[t], 2 Pi, -Pi], angle[t], angle2[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
      PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(4\)]\)", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(3\)]\)"}, 
      ImageSize -> 250]}, 
   Table[Column[{Show[lp, 
       Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
         Point[{j, Mod[theta[j], 2 Pi, -Pi]}], Purple, 
         Point[{j, angle[j]}]}]], anim[j]}], {j, 0, 2, 0.01}]];
```

[image]

Comment: Um, I think the distance between `pos1` and `pos2` is supposed to remain fixed at `r3 = 348` for all `t`.

Comment: @Rahul you are abosolutely right!...different sized disks...I will correct

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you! It was exactly what I needed...

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho  please note that I have changed R3 as with the value you provided the system would not work. Thank you for accepting. Please note, however, that there are likely to be better answers than mine (elegance, efficiency, instructiveness- any or all of these). If this occurs feel free to change your choice. Finally, I remain a little confused at what you wanted. I only mention this as (I hope) constructive advice for presenting future questions. Good luck:)